# Magento 2.4 Best way setup with Docker environment

Tags: magento2, setup, docker, local, magento2.4

What is the best way to Configure Docker environment with Magento 2.4. If some know please give me a solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use these files to setup you docker environment easy to use visit link - https://github.com/markoshust/docker-magento

I hope so it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following docker image

```
wolfsellers/magento2-cloud-local:linux-apache-phpfpm74
```

, it is already optimized to run magento 2.4.

Although you will also need elasticsearch 7

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer solution provided by Warden - https://warden.dev.

Good documentation, extremely simple to install with different services for different projects, support of local domains for development.

Answer (score 0):

I use MeanBee docker for Magento 2: https://github.com/meanbee/docker-magento2
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these repo https://github.com/echo-magento/docker-magento2

Features:

- Magento 2.4
- Apache
- PHP 7.1, PHP 7.2, PHP 7.3
- Xdebug
- Composer 1.10.17
- MariaDB 10.4.13
- Elasticsearch 7.6
- Varnish 6.4
- Redis
- MailHog
- n98-magerun

Comment: Project directory "/var/www/html/." is not empty.  
error on install magento

Answer (score 0):

If you use https://github.com/echo-magento/docker-magento2 and get the error message "Project directory "/var/www/html/." is not empty", you might have forgotten to remove *index.php*.

From the documentation:

To install the latest version of Magento 2:

```
bin/shell
rm index.php
install-magento2
```

P.S. I would have liked to comment on [Hamendra Sunthwal's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/317821/magento-2-4-best-way-setup-with-docker-environment/355111#comment487348_330412) comment, unfortunately I cannot comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

here is another `#docker` configuration for `Magento` `2.4.4`

https://github.com/magenx/Magento-2-docker-configuration

**Stack components in use:**

- `MariaDB` - high performing open source relational database, forked from MySQL.
- `Nginx` - Official build of Nginx.
- `PHP 8.1` - PHP scripting language.
- `Varnish` - is an HTTP accelerator
  designed for content-heavy dynamic web sites as well as APIs.
- `ElasticSearch` - is a powerful open source search and
  analytics engine that makes data easy to explore.
- `Redis` x2 - key-value store that functions as a data structure
  server.
- `RabbitMQ` - is an open source multi-protocol
  messaging broker.
- `NodeJS` - is a JavaScript-based platform.
- `PHPMyAdmin` - a web interface for MySQL and MariaDB.
- `Certbot` - Official build of EFF's Certbot tool for obtaining TLS/SSL certificates from Let's Encrypt.
- [`Composer`]
- [`Cron`]